# Brackets Editor by Adobe , run script extensions are they work with most recent v?

Tags: editor, adobe-brackets

it's Aug 2018 and  I try my lovely Brackets editor to run Ruby script and display output on Panel (not on popup) . And I see that most extensions can not be installed, giving some error, like for major advertised    I see that it's 3 year old+. [Here their gitHub](https://github.com/kmashint/brackets-builder)
[image]
[image: Error message here]

The only one that works is  by SaiintBrisson(c). Alas it output into popup window. and I can see it's updated in 2018 so it's fresh.
Anybody know if any extension avail for my case ? Tried to reach dev team as well but looks like they don't on arena for last 2  years too.
I'm on WIndows .
[image]

Comment: Si, probably they abandoned this product, too many editors